# What's the bzr equivalent to git clone --depth HEAD

Tags: git, version-control, bazaar

I'm wondering how to do `git clone --depth HEAD` with BZR, because I don't need the whole branch history.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `git clone` had a `--HEAD` option.  What version of `git` are you using?

Comment: Whoops I missed something. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to checkout the files and none of the history?  The equivalent of an `svn export`?

Comment: Yeah, I want to work on a project called Openshot which is in BZR, but I don't need the history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [lightweight checkout](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-guide/using_checkouts.html#getting-a-lightweight-checkout) in Bazaar.

Answer (score 5):

Bazaar supports [lightweight checkouts](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/development/en/user-guide/using_checkouts.html#getting-a-lightweight-checkout) with the `--lightweight` switch.

```
bzr checkout --lightweight lp:openshot
```

Comment: I'm trying to grab a remote repo and not export a local one. Sorry :(

Comment: Though, in this particular project, that is unlikely to take much less to download.  The checkout is 50 megs and the repository is 57.  Because of the efficient way which systems like Git and Bazaar store changes, this is very often the case and it's not worth the hassle to do a lightweight checkout to save a little disk space.